# Passing ViewModel values to MVC Controller action method on button or ActionLink click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, razor-pages

I have a asp.net/razor page with a couple of drop downs and I'm try to create a button or actionlink that calls a method named "AssignRole" in the "AccountController" class and passes the values selected in the drop downs to that method. I've been experimenting with various approaches but none of them quite work correctly:

```
    @model SpecSelRepos.Models.AccountViewModels.ManageRolesViewModel

    <fieldset>
        <label for="selectUserName">Users:</label>
        <select asp-for="ManageRolesUser" asp-items="Model.Users"></select>
        &nbsp;
        <label for="selectRoleName">Roles:</label>
        <select asp-for="ManageRolesRole" asp-items="Model.Roles"></select>
        &nbsp;

        @*button 1*@
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AssignRole", "Account"))
        {
            <input type="submit" value="Add User to Role" name="buttonAddUserToRole">


         }

        @*button 2*@
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" name="assignRole" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AssignRole", "Account", new { email = Model.ManageRolesUser, role = Model.ManageRolesRole })'"></button>

        @*link 1*@
        @Html.ActionLink("Assign Role", "AssignRole", "Account", new { email = Model.ManageRolesUser, role = Model.ManageRolesRole }, null)

        @*link 2*@
        @Html.ActionLink("Assign Role", "AssignRole", "Account", new { email = Model.ManageRolesUser, role = Model.ManageRolesRole })

    </fieldset>
```

In the class AccountController I have the following action method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AssignRole(string email, string role)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = GetUserByEmail(email);
            if(null == user)
            {
                return Content("No user with given email:" + email);
            }
            // if the role exists, assign the role to the user
            if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
            {
                if(!await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role))
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
                    return Content("Role assigned: " + GetUserRoles(user));
                }
                else
                {
                    return Content ("User is in role: " + role + ": " + GetUserRoles(user));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Role: " + role + " does not exist");
            }
        }
```

Clicking button 1 has no apparent effect. Button 2 and both links appear to call the AssignRole method but all 3 throw a null value error:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: email
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(string email)
SpecSelRepos.Controllers.AccountController.GetUserByEmail(string email) in AccountController.cs
+                return _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email).Result;
SpecSelRepos.Controllers.AccountController+<AssignRole>d__10.MoveNext() in AccountController.cs
+                ApplicationUser user = GetUserByEmail(email);
```

So it seems that the method is getting called as desired but the values from the view model are getting passed as null rather than the values selected in the drop down boxes.

This is the view model class:

```
public class ManageRolesViewModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public ManageRolesViewModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            Users = new SelectList(userManager.Users.ToList());
            Roles = new SelectList(roleManager.Roles.ToList());
        }

        public SelectList Users;
        public SelectList Roles;
        public string ManageRolesUser { get; set; }//contains the specific user the user selects
        public string ManageRolesRole { get; set; }//contains the specific role the user selects

        public List<ApplicationUser> GetUsersInRole(string role)
        {
            var users = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role).Result.ToList();
            return users;
        }
    }
```

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your view to look like the following, I have used a form instead with a form method & action, this will ensure any inputs inside the form are serialized to parameters matching the same name as them

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.ManageRolesViewModel

<fieldset>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AssignRole", "Account", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <span>
            <label for="email">Users:</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("email", @Model.Users)
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="role">Roles:</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("role", @Model.Roles)
        </span>

        <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="assignRole"/>
    }

</fieldset>
```

Since "email" and "role" match parameters in the controller signature, then the selected ID's will be passed up (not text values)

This is of course on the predicate that the selectList you're passing down to the view has "dataValueField" and "dataTextField" populated.

I have also (not necessarily required) attributed your AssignRoles method with: 
        [HttpGet]

But that's just for verbosity's sake. I'm a  stickler for consistency :)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks mate.